# Not able to get User details from HttpRequest header in JSP to do SSO with Windows Authentication

Tags: java, jsp, iis, jboss, single-sign-on

I am using JBoss-4.2.3.GA and have configured IIS to **Integrated Windows Authentication** and have disabled anonymous access.

I created a JSP page with the following code -

```
<% out.print(request.getHeader("Proxy-Remote-User")); %>
```

Which displays null and doesn't get the User Name.

But if I try it using ASP with -

```
Request.ServerVariables("AUTH_USER")
```

It gives me the correct User Name.

I tried other methods in request object like -

```
out.print(request.getHeader("AUTH_USER"));
out.print(request.getUserPrincipal());
out.print(request.getHeaderNames());
out.print(request.getRemoteUser());
```

But all of them gave null values.

The list of Headers in the request object that I am getting are - 

*connection, accept, accept-encoding, accept-language, authorization, cookie, host, user-agent, tomcatworkeridx6a6b0000, content-length.*

I also looked into the server.xml in the JBoss Directory and found **enableLookups="false"** 
I changed it to  **enableLookups="true"**  but it automatically got modified to  **enableLookups="false"**  on server restart. Is it necessary to have enableLookups as true? If so, how to stop it from being set to false automatically when I restart the JBoss server?

How can I get the remote user name from the request object?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For JBoss I had to write an asp and get the User Name by Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_USER") and then pass it to my JSP

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `tomcatAuthentication="false"` on your AJP connector object as mentioned [here](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/latest/config/ajp.html). Your Connector in server.xml should look something like the following:

```
<Connector port="8009" address="${jboss.bind.address}"
  emptySessionPath="true" enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" 
  protocol="AJP/1.3" connectionTimeout="600000" maxThreads="200"
  tomcatAuthentication="false" />
```

(I'm not 100% certain that applies to the AS as well as the stand-alone web server, but it seems worth a shot)

As noted in the link above the `enableLookups` property merely controls whether `request.getRemoteHost()` actually performs a DNS query or not and, consequently, has no bearing on getting the `REMOTE_USER` header set properly

Comment: It works only on Weblogic Server and not on JBoss. For JBoss I had to write an asp and get the User Name by Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_USER") and then pass it to my JSP.